# Ping spikes into the thousands in only roblox

Tags: networking, roblox

My ping has been spiking in Roblox for about a month now and it's just unplayable. For some context I have ethernet and this just happened out of nowhere. Things I've tried.
Factor reset pc,
reset network,
reset router,
allow thru firewall,
any optimizations and fixes that could be found online.

So far nothing has worked. When played on other devices in my home I face the same ping spikes. If anyone has any solutions of fixes, I would greatly appreciate them. This is what happens when I tracert roblox. [image]

Comment: Did you try reinstalling Roblox, or play from a fresh account?

Comment: Yes, I've done both and I've even tried to play Roblox from the Microsoft store, the issue persists.

Comment: What's your ping roundtrip time? If you use a different network/ISP (eg go to a friend's house) does the issue persist and do you have similar latency on the ping? Do you have any software such as virus scanner, download analyzer, net nanny, corporate monitoring software, etc which might be interfering with your Internet connection? Is the latency the same over WiFi vs Ethernet?

Comment: Does this happen on one roblox game specifically, or is it the platform as a whole?

Comment: I don't know how to check my roundtrip time. Also, when connecting to my hotspot on my mobile hotspot on my pc the lag spikes go away. But when trying Wi-Fi or ethernet they are there. Going to other places and playing mobile Roblox there's no lag spikes. But mobile Roblox using my home Wi-Fi has problems. I factory reset my pc and the issue persisted so it's not a software. @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

Comment: The fact that you're seeing it at home on your home connection, both with wifi and ethernet, but not elsewhere, makes me suspicious that the issue is going to be with your internet connection. It may be your ISP -- probably worth calling them up. Since you're seeing it on both your wifi and your ethernet, it's probably not your router or your wifi network, but it might be your modem or the internet connection itself.

Comment: Does this happen with games and/or platforms other than Roblox? I agree with Roddy, this is seeming a lot like an overall internet problem rather than just a Roblox problem.

Comment: The only weird thing is I only see problems on Roblox and no other games, thank you though. @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas

Comment: No its only Roblox, thanks though. @xTerrene